# Is there any easy way using Asp.net Routing to remove .aspx extension using Asp.net Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am using Asp.Net 4.0 and for generating SEO Friendly Urls I use Asp.Net Routing methods like;

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add("BikeSaleRoute", new Route
    (
       "bikes/sale",
       new CustomRouteHandler("~/Contoso/Products/Details.aspx")
    ));
}
```

Handling it in Application_Start Method

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

 }
```

What I am trying to write is a method using Asp.net Routing that can remove .aspx extensions from all my pages regardless of their directory level (even the starting page Default.aspx). Any help in this regard, please?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/14762/how-to-remove-the-aspx-from-Asp-Net-urls-and-how-to-cut-t.aspx

Comment: Kamlesh Arya, I need this using Asp.net Routing Technique not something requiring IIS to confiqure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use URL Re-writing in IIS or in Web.Config and can do by following code snippet, place following code in "Global.asax".

> `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
>   {
>        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForDefault", "Default", "~/Default.aspx");
>   }`

Good Luck

Comment: Use www.example.com/Default instead of using this URL: www.example.com/Default.aspx, it will work.

Comment: Yes working now, but this is only for one page. What if we want a general method that can work for every page within the project?

Comment: Look dear you can use this method for lots of pages like: routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForDefault", "Page1", "~/Page1.aspx"); routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForDefault", "Page2", "~/Page2.aspx");, there is not shortcut to write single line to remove the .aspx extension, if you will use URL Re-writing which is standard, again you will write different for different pages.. Hope you understand it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried searching alternative but could not find one under the boundaries of "Routing" except using separate rules for every pages.

Comment: Yes go with this it's fair enough to start, and after that start working with IIS URL Re-Writing. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general solution for all the pages in your project you can use the package here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

Otherwise you can use this in Global.asax for every page in your application:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
        void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("InteriorServices", "InteriorServices", "~/InteriorServices.aspx");
        }
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
 }
```

Comment: For the code above you provided- this works only for a specific page. a need something that can work for every page within the solution. Thanks